# Get index of parent given a value of a child array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the index of the parent given an element inside the children, for example, I have a `list` variable `(2) [Array(1), Array(2)]` with this structure:

```
[
    [
        {id: "1",contactType: {id: "phoneNumber",company: {id: "01",name: "Company01"}},value: "5555555555"},
    ],
    [
        {id: "2",contactType: {id: "phoneNumber",company: {id: "03",name: "Company03"}},value: "7777777777"},
        {id: "3",contactType: {id: "phoneNumber",company: {id: "05",name: "Company05"}},value: "8888888888"},
    ],
]
```

I tried using `includes` and `findIndex` to verify if such element exist first and then get the parent index:

```
list.includes('5555555555', 0);
```

I expected to get `true` because I asked `include` to begin searching in index 0 of the list exactly where `"5555555555"` element is, but i got `false` instead.

Also tried with:

```
list.findIndex(x => x.value === '5555555555');
```

I expected `0` since element `5555555555` is in parent 0 index. But got `-1` instead.

I also tried using `flat()` to get into the children and the use `includes`, but then I lose the `0` and `1` index of the original `list`.

**Expected output:**

`foo(list,'7777777777');` should return `1` since that element is inside the second array of the `list` or `foo(list,'8888888888');` should also return `1` since that element is also inside the second array of the `list`.

Can someone guide me on how to approach this issue?

Comment: mabye you can use a for loop where you compare value of full list to the value of it in parent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Array.findIndex` with condition

```js
const data = [
[
    {id: "1",contactType: {id: "phoneNumber",company: {id: "01",name: "Company01"}},value: "5555555555"},
],
[
    {id: "2",contactType: {id: "phoneNumber",company: {id: "03",name: "Company03"}},value: "7777777777"},
    {id: "3",contactType: {id: "phoneNumber",company: {id: "05",name: "Company05"}},value: "8888888888"},
],
];

const index = data.findIndex(item => item.findIndex(node => node.value === "5555555555") > -1);
console.log(index)
```